# Insert a Plugin Setting Value as Shortcode Attribute

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I wrote a plugin.

One of the plugin's settings is a URL/page.

I want my client to be able to continue to use the theme's page builder, to create any buttons that will link to the URL that is entered in the plugin's settings.

The client could enter the URL manually for every button they create, but this would be tedious, and will become a massive pain should the URL in the plugin's settings change.

So, I want to be able to use the plugin's URL setting value as the URL attribute of a third-party button shortcode.

Is this possible? Something like:

```
[button url="{get the plugin's URL setting}"][/button]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely possible.

You would need to add the shortcode functionality to your plugin. Best to use a unique name to avoid conflicts (not 'button').
in your plugin php file add the function and register it with the add_shortcode function like so:

```
function shortcodeName_function( $atts ) {
  // add attribute handling and get the 'url' parameter
  $output = '<button a href="'. $url . '" class="button">';
  return $output;
}


add_shortcode( 'shortcodeName', 'shortcodeName_function');
```

Now u can use now a short code with this name, when the plugin is activated.

```
[shortcodeName]
```

See the link of the wordpress documentation for more info on parameter handling: [wordpress shortcode api](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

**EDIT**: ah sorry, I think I missed the point a bit. What you could do is - store the plugin url setting in a **cookie** and check for the cookie value in the short code.

Answer (score 0):

When shortcode have not attribute url you can provide default settings url in shortcode return output.

Like this

```
add_shortcode( 'button', 'shortcode_function_button');

 function shortcode_function_button( $atts ){

    $attr =  shortcode_atts( array(
        'url' =>  get_option( 'button_default_url' ) , // get your setting default url if shortcode have not
    ), $atts );                                        // attr url="http://example.com" then it use default
                                                       // setting url

    return '<a href="'.esc_url($attr['url']).'" class="button">Button</a>';
 }
```

If already build shortcode in plugin or theme then find shortcode callback function and change atts in this way.

If probleming in find third party shortcode callback name check in your plugin file all registered shortcodes with callback.

```
global $shortcode_tags;

print_r( $shortcode_tags ); 

// show all shortcodes with callback
/*Array
(
    [embed] => __return_false
    [wp_caption] => img_caption_shortcode
    [caption] => img_caption_shortcode
    [gallery] => gallery_shortcode
    [playlist] => wp_playlist_shortcode
    [audio] => wp_audio_shortcode
    [video] => wp_video_shortcode
    [button] => button_shortcode

)*/
```

If do you not want to any change in thired party shortcode and manage in your plugin

1. Remove shortcode previously declared thired party plugin and add in your plugin top of file.

   `remove_shortcode('button');`  // https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_shortcode/
2. Recreate same shortcode tag after remove but use own callback name and work same as thired party shortcode like this

   ```
   add_shortcode( 'button', 'your_own_callback' );

   function your_own_callback( $atts, $content ){

   $attr =  shortcode_atts( array(
   'url' =>  get_option( 'button_default_url' ) , // Use same atts thired party using atts
   ), $atts );

   return button_shortcode( $attr, $content); // Use thired party callback function name.
   }
   ```